# Laravel 5.5 Validation with OR/ELSE conditional

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation, php-7.1

i'm new to laravel and i would like to know if there are a way to use or/else conditional in $rules, because I am struggling trying to do the following validation: 
If the field is Z the size must be y, else, x.
I tried this, but it always validade data with size:11

```
'type   => 'required',
'field' => ['required', ('type == 1' ? 'size:11' : 'size:14')],
```

Anyone has a clue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Form request validation so you can do something like this:

```
$rules = [
   'type' => 'required',
   'field' =>  ['required'];
];

$rules['field'][] = ($this->input('type') == 1) ? 'size:11' : 'size:14';

return $rules;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Validator , 
Refer Link:    https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: but I am using laravel validator